# Кто автор афоризма об улыбке Джоконды?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Не пытайтесь искать тайну в улыбке Джоконды — она улыбается тщете ваших поисков."
Красиво, волшебно, но кто автор этого афоризма?

Comment: Вы пробовали искать (автора), но неудачно?

Comment: Вы и правда считаете этоткрасивым и волшебным? Ну дела...

Comment: Вы и правда считаете это красивым и волшебным? Ну дела...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Портрет придворной дамы в прозрачном покрывале***

*– Пытаетесь разгадать тайну Джоконды? Боюсь, это невозможно...

– Все пытаются разгадать тайну ее улыбки, как улыбки женщины, а ведь ее улыбка – это улыбка самой тайны. И она смотрит на нас всех и смеется, потому что знает – улыбка тайны непостижима.*
[**Наталия Вико, Тело черное, белое, красное**](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/81898/54/Viko_-_Telo_chernoe%2C_beloe%2C_krasnoe.html)

По смыслу — очень близко к Вашему афоризму.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, очень похоже. Наталию Вико не читал - видимо, параллельное движение мысли.